# Why do the rebels stay on their bases?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, a-new-hope

In **A New Hope** and **The Force Awakens** the rebels stay at their bases. Yet they are up against impossible odds with next to nothing to do but watch the battle unfold. They could have left and then if the planet was destroyed it wouldn't have affected the rebellion that much.

**Why did they stay in their respective bases?**

Comment: *"Evacuate? In our moment of triumph?"*. No, wait. That's the other guys.

Comment: It's where all their cool Rebel-branded stuff is.  That stuff takes time to pack, and they had to do silly things like organize and control battles, man comm consoles, etc.

Comment: @Jeff I'd assume they would be controlling the battles but as I remember the films only really show the main generals standing around mot doing much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### ANH

**Leia said that there wasn't time. Commander Willard accepted her recommendation without question.**

> *“We’re badly unprepared for battle, Your Highness. **Perhaps we should
> evacuate instead?** Here—” Commander Willard motioned to two nearby
> technicians. “Take this droid into the command center and download any
> information he has about the Death Star.”*
>
> ...
>
> ***“There isn’t time,”** Leia said. “Commander, if we fail to stop the Death Star now, other planets will be annihilated.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

**The leaders of the Rebellion stayed on the base in order to be martyred, guaranteeing future support for a new Rebellion to arise from the ashes of the old one.**

> When a tall, dignified gentleman with too many deaths on his soul
> moved to stand by the far side of the screen, Solo turned his
> attention to him, as did everyone else in the room. As soon as an
> expectant silence had gripped the crowd, **General Jan Dodonna adjusted
> the tiny mike on his chest and indicated the small group seated close
> to him.**
>
> *“You all know these people,” he intoned with quiet power. **“They are
> the Senators and Generals whose worlds have given us support, whether
> open or covert. They have come to be with us in what may well prove to
> be the decisive moment.”** He let his gaze touch many in the crowd, and
> none who were so favored remained unmoved.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

### TFA

**The base itself remains fully operational, preparing to receive injured pilots and provide command and control facilities. We can reasonably assume that *non-essential* personnel were shipped off at the first sign of danger.**

The "crowd" at the end appears to consist of engineers, officers, various and medical personnel, all of whom would be needed to ensure the safe operation of the base **in the event of a victory.**

> *Poe, having called in his teams in relief after spotting the Falcon
> leaving Starkiller Base, was waiting for the ship as it touched down
> on D’Qar, settling into a vacant space between the remaining
> Resistance X-wings.*
>
> *Even before the boarding ramp hit the ground,
> Chewbacca was emerging, moving fast with the still-breathing Finn in
> his arms. **Medical personnel and officers waiting to meet them escorted
> the pair inside the complex.***

Comment: Have you got any quote from TFA as well?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Nothing as convincing. The base is probably operating on a skeleton crew, hence why the crowd at the end is so small.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons that make sense:

1. When you send your soldiers/pilots into battle, it doesn't give them much confidence if you take an action that assumes they're going to fail.
2. In the case of ANH and TFA, these were all-or-nothing battles.  For instance, in ANH, the starfighters attacking the Death Star were all that was left of the rebel forces.  There wasn't much of a fleet left to save.  By staying at the base they were providing a service in co-ordinating the attack.  It's likely (avoiding spoilers here) that they were missing the troop carrying capacity to evacuate the ground troops from the base.

This is different in ESB.  During the battle of Hoth, the soldiers and pilots are told their mission is to hold off the Imperial forces long enough to allow time for the rebels to escape.  Once that mission is accomplished, the order is given to retreat.